# run ajax function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to load  content and dump json on page:
**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Learning</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  body { background-color: #ddd; }
  #container { height: 100%; width: 100%; display: table; }
  #inner { vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; }
  #gauge_div { width: 120px; margin: 0 auto; }
</style>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <div id="animal-info"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var animalContainer = document.getElementById("animal-info");

var ourRequeast = new XMLHttpRequest();
var loaded = document.getElementById("body");

body.addEventListener("onload", function(){


ourRequeast.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
ourRequeast.onload = function() {
// console.log(ourRequeast.responseText);
// var ourData = ourRequeast.responseText;
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequeast.responseText);
// console.log(ourData[0])

renderHTML(ourData);
}
ourRequeast.send();
});

function renderHTML(data){
    animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'testing 123');
}
```

so I am hoping that it should print **"testing 123"** on page load but its neither giving error nor showing anything

Comment: Try `window.onoad=function(){**Place Ajax Call Here...**}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use the [document ready statement](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('this is run on page load');
    myFunction();
});
```

Comment: I just realised , in addition to your answer, I needed to put `<div id="animal-info"></div>` before `<script src="main.js"></script>` why is that ?

Comment: It might be because main.js doesn't see the div since it is loaded after the element. This doesn't make sense though because document ready is triggered after the DOM is done loading.

Comment: That is why I was placing it after call to main.js

Answer (score 0):

Event types passed to `addEventListener` are expected to be without the `on` prefix. Instead of `addEventListener("onload", function () {` use `addEventListener("load", function () {`.

Also, you're attaching event listener to variable `body`, but this variable is not defined in the code. It may still work, if there is an element with `id="body"` in the document (backward-compatible browser behaviour), but I wouldn't rely on this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to wrap your whole code in the following;

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do stuff here
});
```

This will execute all of the code when the DOM has finished loading. This is supported by pretty much all browsers but those not really used anymore, like IE8.

You can also do this just for calling the function, but some variables that get DOM elements might not grab the nodes properly if they are yet to load.

Complete JS for example, also tested in JSFiddle. Works fine.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var animalContainer = document.getElementById("animal-info");

  var ourRequeast = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var loaded = document.getElementById("body");

  ourRequeast.open('GET', 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
    ourRequeast.onload = function() {
    // console.log(ourRequeast.responseText);
    // var ourData = ourRequeast.responseText;
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequeast.responseText);
    //console.log(ourData[0])

    renderHTML(ourData);
  }
  ourRequeast.send();

  function renderHTML(data){
      animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'testing 123');
  }
});
```